# How to use the useMasterKey option saving from the Parse Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I tried to save something to the User table and it was failing saying that I couldn't save to the User table without a session.

Reading through the docs (http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#save), it looks like you should be able to use it like so:

```
object.save(null, {
    useMasterKey: true, 
    success: function(results){ .. },
    error: { .. }
});
```

.. after having initialized Parse with the master key.

However, this isn't working for me.

What should I be doing here?

*Update*: I'm an idiot. I *wasn't* in fact initializing Parse with the master key as I should have been.

Comment: could you mention how you are supposed to initialize it. Docs are dead. :(

Comment: somewhere in your app you'll have Parse.initialize.. it takes several params